# Adding a Chrome plugin without signing in

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

I'll provide an exact account of what I'm trying to do, in case the answer can vary depending on the plug-in.

At work, I've installed the [Feed Intent Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/feed-intent-viewer/oceapojkdgeophkjdijkpbjifdnfimdh) plugin without incident [With the latest Chrome version].
When I wanted to install the same plugin into my Chrome browser at home, I was prompted to sign in to Chrome. When I refused to do that, the browser didn't allow me to install the extension.

I was signed in in neither of those cases, yet I was able to install an extension in the first case and not in the second. Why? Can I somehow work around it?

Comment: I've tried googling around, of course, in case it needs to be said.

Comment: It just occurred to me that I probably was signed into gmail at work, and not at home.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to sign in to GMail. The browser still displayed an option to "Sign In To Chrome", so that probably is a different thing altogether.